# Space with a roof on it

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm describing a shop floor. The total area is 8000 square meters, 2000 of which are ??

Is "covered" the right word? It doesn't sound right to me. What I want to say is that it's an indoor space with a roof on it.

Comment: It sounds like you are describing a [dropped ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropped_ceiling).

Comment: Why can't you just use *indoor*?

Comment: Are the other 6000 square meters "covered"? Hard to imagine a shop floor out in the elements. It would help users respond if you describe your shop floor more fully.

Comment: I'm with @jera saying its indoors implies that it is covered. However more details on what the property layout is would help.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to say is that it's an indoor space with a roof on it.

Why not say ***roofed***?

Google Books returns 3,140 results for "roofed space", among them:

> Next, a roofed space is required to shield the family against
>   excessive sun.
>
> The medium bus stations will have 12 to 20 platforms with a minimum of
>   3,000 square feet roofed space exclusively for use by the passengers
>   apart from additional space to commercial stalls and for
>   administrative purposes.
>
> … 174 square meters of space per inhabitant, which included an
>   average of 8.9 square meters of interior, roofed space per person.
>
> Some screen between the backs of the houses, some paved space and even
>   a small roofed space may be desirable and very useful.